# Evaluate triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{2}{(1 - z)^2 \sqrt{z^2 + 1}}\, dz \, dx \, dy $$

I'm starting to learn multivariable calculus and I encounter this problem, but I currently stuck on finding this integral. I only know how to do substitution and integration by parts for one variable and my approach is trying to manipulate $ (1 - z)^2 \sqrt{z^2 + 1} $ so that I can apply the two methods with $ dz $, but I still haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Have you changed the order of integration?

Comment: You mean doing $ dx $ and $ dy $ first? But eventually I'll still have to find a way to integrate $ (1 - t)^2 \sqrt{t^2 + 1} $ for some variable $ t $ though, so how can that help?

Comment: You might have additional terms to help with the integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the order of integration: 
the integration area is $0\leq z\leq x \leq y \leq 1$

imagine For a fixed $0<z<1$, the area of $z\leq x \leq y \leq 1$ is $\frac{1}{2}(1-z)^2$
So the integral can be written as $$\int_0^1\frac{(1-z)^2}{(1-z)^2\sqrt{1+z^2}}dz=\log(z+\sqrt{1+z^2})|_{z=1}=\log{(1+\sqrt{2})}$$

Answer (score 1):

Our integral can be written as
$$ \iiint_{0\leq z\leq x\leq y \leq 1} \frac{dz}{(1-z)^2\sqrt{1+z^2}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-z)^2\,dz}{(1-z)^2\sqrt{1+z^2}}=\color{red}{\text{arcsinh}(1)}=\log(1+\sqrt{2}). $$
The first equality is a consequence of the fact that, for a fixed $z\in(0,1)$, the measure of the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: z\leq x\leq 1,z\leq y\leq 1\}$ is precisely $(1-z)^2$.